# What to do when app crashes and logcat shows no errors

Tags: android, logcat

The app works fine in the emulator, but after installation on a phone, it crashes every time on launch, and logcat shows no errors.

What am I supposed to do when something like this happens?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*My Suggestion for easier resolution of your problem :*

Run the app from the eclipse in **debug** mode  on the Phone . It will make it run on debug mode. You will most likely get more debug output.

1. Turn on ADB in the phone.
2. Connect the Phone to the PC
3. Run as "Debug Configuration" from eclipse.
4. It should run from your phone and Eclipse will ask for your choice for first time before running that.

---

Turning the *Debug Mode* on ( Note : This **isn't** the 'ADB connection' we are referring to ) , It will enable further logging of the application and doesn't do garbage collection  normally.

( You will notice a *'Waiting for debug connection'* dialogue  , if the applications are forced to work in debug mode ).

For e.g :It makes the Async threads keep running and doesn't stop running. Crude and irrelevant for your case . But just as an example.

So , Since the Applications in the phone are **forced** to run in debug mode ,  it will get the logcat with detailed errors down to the specific threads.

However, the debug mode is *better used* when it's used in conjunction with **"Debug As" run configuration** from Eclipse. And keep in mind that it will *automatically* turn on that debug application mode  ( And there by the dialog box also) , the logcat will show you more details and  plus it **will break-point** at the errors which occur ,in their sequence of occurence.

---

*Regarding what Ares told,* 
When you want to do the debugging of a process directly,

1. You can go to the DDMS panel in Eclipse,
2. On the right side tab menu *Devices* ,
3. Select the process you want to debug . and click on the green symbol ( Says, Start Debugging process )
4. It will automatically go to the source when it breaks if you have the source code in that eclipse work-space.

Comment: Is this equivalent to the solution proposed by @Ares?

Comment: @user1301428 Yes. But more practical. When you debug the application directly in your phone from eclipse ,instead of using the emulator,  You will get more practical logcat output. And when you debug using your phone instead of emulator, the Eclipse/DDMS will automatically turn your phone into debug mode  for that user session ( Read as , till restarting phone ).  Ares suggested you to  turn on the Debug mode on phone  using the DDMS panel  However, It would be more appropriate to directly debug your phone with the app than just turning on the debug mode from DDMS alone.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what happens when I only turn on ADB mode from DDMS and what happens when I run the app in debug mode?

Comment: @user1301428  ,See the edit.  And accept this as solution if your doubts are cleared. :)

Comment: Thank you for the edit. One last question: so basically, turning the debug mode on is what Ares suggested?

Comment: @user1301428 I'm assuming that Ares was suggesting you to make the applications /processes run in 'debug mode'. And that is not exactly the same as turning the debug mode on (ADB) .

Answer (score 5):

Additional hint:

On huawei phones, logcat doesn't show debug messages and excpetions, if the phone is in default system settings.

In order to enable logcat full logs on Huawei phones, you must do the following:

- Open the factory settings menu by dialing `*#*#2846579#*#*`
- Navigate to Project Menu / Background Setting / Log setting
- On older phones: define the log availability (log switch) and level (log level setting).
- On never phones: tick  AP Log (which seems to enable app logging in general) and CP Log (seems to enable debug logging)
- Close the menu with your backbutton (no restart needed)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18395092/1075072

Answer (score 1):

Install a tool like [AndroidSystemInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi) that can show you the logfile on the phone - even when you are away from the host computer.

It is pretty unusual that Android leaves no trace whatsoever.

Does your app perhaps require features that the phone does not have (e.g. a camera or gps or nfc)?

Comment: No, I don't try to use a feature that my phone doesn't have. Thanks for the app suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you should go to DDMS, then click on device's name or android.os in `Devices` panel. And turn your device in debug mode.

Comment: I've already enabled debug mode from the phone settings, isn't this the same thing as the one you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can reset adb (In Devices -> View menu -> Reset adb)
2. Click on the selected online device/emulator to show the logcat
3. Disconnect the cable and again connect it. (Or restart the emulator)
4. Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my emulator and cleaned my build.  This got rid of both the non-logging and the spurious crash I was having