# Huawei, logcat not showing the log for my app?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat, huawei-mobile-services

OK, logcat is showing system logs but it is not showing application log on my Huawei Ascend. If I switch to another device such as my Galaxy Nexus or Nexus 7 then for the same app (same APK even) log is displayed.

The Huawei Ascend is running Android 4.1.1, it has USB debugging switched on in developer options. This occurs for logcat run from either the command line or from IntelliJ. And I'm making sure that the correct device is selected - in fact I'm only plugging a single device in at a time. I've tried restarting adb, clearing it's buffer etc

I can see that the app is starting on the Huawei, I even get system logs showing that the Activity has started. But unlike on the other devices I get no app log in the Activity#onCreate (or from anywhere else).

```
08-08 20:55:44.050: INFO/WindowManager(431): Switching to real app window: Window{41ae8780 au.com.xandar.wirelesstiming.timekeeper/au.com.xandar.wirelesstiming.timekeeper.TimeKeeperActivity paused=false}
08-08 20:55:44.180: INFO/ActivityManager(431): Displayed au.com.xandar.wirelesstiming.timekeeper/.TimeKeeperActivity: +387ms
```

How can the application log not be getting delivered?

Comment: Maybe you've applied a certain filter in the LogCat output - go check it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't logcat show anything in my Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android)

Comment: @CamilStaps because this problem is specific to Huawei phones.

Comment: That doesn't really matter, the point is that it has been answered elsewhere already.

Comment: @CamilStaps This question has not been answered elsewhere. Hene the number of people that it has helped compared to the other.

Comment: Yes, it has: your own answer points to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10963065/1544337 which answers your question.

Comment: @CamilStaps Read the 2 questions. This **question** has not been asked elsewhere.

Comment: For meizu https://stackoverflow.com/a/42822508/4592448

Comment: this solution did worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691076/logcat-not-showing-errors-from-my-huawei-p9-phone

Answer (score 491, accepted):

OK, since I had another Huawei Ascend I ran into the same problem. This time I have the exact answer. Follow these instructions (from denispyr's answer on  [Why doesn't logcat show anything in my Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android/10963065#10963065))

> Dial
>
> ```
> *#*#2846579#*#*
> ```
>
> and you will see a hidden menu. Go to the Project Menu > Background Setting > Log setting and define the log availability (log switch) and level (log level setting).

And then make sure you restart your phone.

Please note this probably only applies to Huawei phones.

Also note that if you're *on a Huawei tablet* (e.g. MediaPad M3), instead of dialing, you launch the **Huawei Calculator** in landscape and enter `()()2846579()()`.

Comment: For Huawei BTV-W09 nothing appeared where "define the log availability (log switch) and level (log level setting)". Instead there are 3 checkBoxes, the first one with the name AP Log was the one that solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 48):

### For Huawei with Android 8.0+

we must dial the code: `*#*#2846579#*#*`

and selecting the option **AP Log** will be enough to display the messages in the LogCat.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 13):

If any one having **Letv Phone (LeEco Le Max 2 or 1)** above solution won't work. Try the below USSD. Fig.1 for reference.

```
Press Dialer *#*#76937#*#*
```

Select **"Enable All Logs"**

[image: Fig.1]

Comment: This does not work on the **Huawei ECO** phone. Any tips?
Model #: **LUA-L23**

Comment: @charlesfranciscodev have you tried *#*#2846579#*#*. As mentioned in above answer

Comment: Thanks. Working with LeECO x527

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using

```
Log.d(TAG, msg);
```

Try this.

```
Log.wtf(TAG, msg);
```

work for me.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me on the **Huawei ECO** phone!

Comment: `Log.wtf()` is designed to a totally unexpected state. It is akin to `SEVERE`. It is certainly not `DEBUG`

Comment: Xd i  think Log.e()/Log.w()/Log.i() work very nice too.

Answer (score 4):

I have a **HUAWEI Y3 II** aka **LUA-L21**.

The **accepted answer didn't work for me**.
It led to some *MTKLogger* settings screen, which is different than described in the answer, and didn't help at all.

### My solution

1. Dial `*#*#2846580#*#*` (please note this code is different from the one in the accepted answer)
2. You just entered a settings screen called *EngineerMode* (again, different from accepted answer's *ProjectMenu*)
3. In the first *Telephony* tab, click the *Log Control* item
4. **Activate both switches** (set *Mtklog control* to *catch all log* and *adb radio log* to *catch radio log by adb*)
5. Back in the previous screen, swipe to the *Log and Debugging* tab
6. Open *Debug Utils*
7. Change *Debug Level* from *User Mode* to **Engineer Mode**
8. For good measure, **restart your phone**

### Screens

Changing *Log control*

[image]
[image]

Changing *Debug utils*

[image]
[image]

### Additional notes

Just to clarify my original problem; logcat was showing **some** of my app's log entries, just **not my own messages** - I saw entries belonging to my process `com.example.myapp`, but never anything I was printing out myself, in my code, using `Log.d("TAG", "hello world");`

There was plenty of stuff like this:

```
4260-4270/com.example.myapp I/art: Debugger is no longer active
4260-4412/com.example.myapp I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:1
4260-4412/com.example.myapp D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
4260-4603/com.example.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
4260-4603/com.example.myapp D/Surface:  Surface::disconnect(this=0xb85285d8,api=1)
4260-4260/com.example.myapp D/ActivityThread: ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@2333cbdf
```

...but never anything like this:

```
4260-4603/com.example.myapp D/MainActivity: hello from onCreate!
```

The above steps solved the issue for me.

Comment: For Huawei CRO-L22 and some other Huawei with MTK works code for engineer mode *#*#14789632#*#*

Comment: Thanks! #*#14789632#*# works on Y5 Lite (CRO-L03)

Answer (score 4):

Some newer versions of Huawei Phones (I am using a Y9s 2019) have some settings changed.

Process is now

Dial *#*#2846579#*#*

Background Settings -> AP LOG Settings -> Open.

If you still can't see the logs, restart both your phone and Android Studio/Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

```
Open your Dialer app and enter the following code: *#*#2846579#*#*.

    1-Enter the Background Settings page.
    2-Click on “Log Settings”
    3-Check all 3 options to enable full logging.
    4-Ignore the "will affect performance" warning.
    5-Reboot the phone.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading a Logcat app(eg aLogCat) on your device itself and see if you are having the same problem.
I know its not a complete solution, but this way you may be able to figure out whats going wrong by reading the application logs.

Comment: This does not work on 4.x.x and above for system logs, only for the concrete application logs with `READ_LOGS` permission set - https://code.google.com/p/alogcat/issues/detail?id=41.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

In Eclipse editor:

Reset adb from windows-->devices and then try again ...

please check your project is highlighted with green color (simply select your projrct name)

Comment: As I said above, I'm using logcat from either command line or IntelliJ. I don't use Eclipse. And second, as I also said above I have already tried resetting adb (multiple times).