# Android Huawei Reading Logcat

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, logcat

I working on an Android app that reads from log cat. It works perfectly on all Android devices except for the Huawei company. I've read a lot of stuff about on the internet, and I saw that logcat is disabled in Huawei.
So I activated it following these steps:

1. Dial *#*#2846579#*#*
2. Go ProjectMenu->Background Setting->Log Setting
3. Set Log switch to on
4. Finally restart your device and enjoy the app

I did that now the logs appear in logcat when I execute the app connected to Eclipse. But Still I can't read from log cat it always returns null:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "logcat", "-c" });
logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "logcat" });
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcat.getInputStream()), 4 * 1024);
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {System.out.println("HELLO");}`

`br.readLine()` always returns null.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Huawei, logcat not showing the log for my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app)

Comment: @Siebe - no, please **take time to read the question** as it states that the procedure you would point to has already been used, **and made a difference** (eclipse now shows logs) but that it is **not the problem this question seeks to solve**.  This question concerns instead reading logs **from within the app**.

Comment: `System Menu/Developer Options/Android Debug`... or does it only work on rooted/modded phones?

Comment: @Der Golem I did this. And if I'm not mistaken this just enables USB debugging