# Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d") returns null

Tags: android, logcat

I'm trying to get the log of my app. Android 4.1.2 (Huawei tablet)

This is the code that I'm using

```
StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        try {  
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");  
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));  


            String line;  
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                

              log.append(line); 
              log.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }  
            System.out.println(line == null);

          } catch (IOException e) { 
             System.out.println("error");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

I have added ther permissions to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

When I try to read it `bufferedReader` is null and nothing is added to `log` variable.

**EDIT:**

I've founded this info

[INFO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18395092/2781852/)

Apparently Huawei devices have service loggin disabled by default. I've tried the solution of the post but it doesn't work for me because "service loggin" option doesn't appears

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Just check this project https://github.com/androidnerds/logger

Comment: I've tried the project on my device and it doesn't start.It closes unexpectly when start

Comment: I've added info to the initial message

Answer (score -2):

```
untime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d"})
```