# Why are Log.d() and Log.v() not printing

Tags: android-studio, logcat

I have the following test code in my Activity:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.e(CLASS_NAME, "ERROR onStart()");
    Log.w(CLASS_NAME, "WARN onStart()");
    Log.i(CLASS_NAME, "INFO onStart()");
    Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "DEBUG onStart()");
    Log.v(CLASS_NAME, "VERBOSE onStart()");
```

On the *logcat* view in Android Studio, it only prints:

```
02-10 15:56:10.190    6194-6194/org.example.my_app E/MyActivity﹕ ERROR onStart()
02-10 15:56:10.190    6194-6194/org.example.my_app W/MyActivity﹕ WARN onStart()
02-10 15:56:10.190    6194-6194/org.example.my_app I/MyActivity﹕ INFO onStart()
```

On top of the box, the menu is set to `Log level: “Verbose”`, and if I go into the menu next to it, choose `“Edit filter configuration”`, `“by Log Level”` is also set to `“Verbose”`. Why are the `Log.d()` and `Log.v()` not printing anything? What might I am missing? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @webo80 You think *that* is strange... Log.d is working for me in one module, but not another!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Android Studio filters lines that have already been logged but Log itself may filter some levels when logging. See [Log.isLoggable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable(java.lang.String,%20int)):

> The default level of any tag is set to `INFO`.

(However on many phone it is actually set to `DEBUG` or `VERBOSE`.)

Comment: Thank you. The rest of the story: This can be changed on tag level on the shell until the next reboot, or by creating a config file. My phone doesn’t recognize the config file. [Here is a blog post](http://vnnotech.in/?p=198) that suggests logging everything to “info” with your own logger class which provides additional filtering.

Comment: it could be device specific try http://stackoverflow.com/a/43999262/2783229

Comment: Take attention to filters dropdown in Logcat pane.

Answer (score 26):

**Accepted answer not working**

My solution:

> when your `Log.d` is not working then `Log.wtf` is work

It's working for me, may be this is helpful to other, who find solution

Comment: Using `Log.wtf` is basically like using `Log.e`, only more severe. So this is not really an improvement over what the question already presents. The OP is trying to get logcat to show *less* severe log levels, D and V.

Comment: what 'wtf' means ...? :D

Comment: WTF - means What a Terrible Failure.

Comment: Log.wtf has indeed appeared as error in logcat, but I mean WTF?! Developing android apps with Eclipse was pretty bad but Studio is just as pathetic.

Comment: At first, I thought that this was a complete joke, but lo and behold the devs did add Log.wtf... Gotta love the coding community. This is now my second favorite right after isUserAGoat()

Answer (score 13):

Fix For meizu phone

> Settings -> Accessibility -> **Developer options** -> advanced
>   logging->set "Allow all"

For Meizu MX4(Flyme 6.1.0.0), M2(Flyme 6.1.0.0G), M5(Flyme 6.3.0.0G) :

> Settings->Accessibility - > **Developer Options** -> Performance
>   optimization -> Advanced logging -> set "Allow all"

[Huawei, logcat not showing the log for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app/43999262#43999262)

For other phone search in "developers options": option "logging" and set  "all".

Answer (score 10):

Turn off your **Developer Option** then **Restart Your Phone** After that **on developer option** It definitely works by sure!!

Answer (score 9):

I've faced also to the same issue. Even following the previous answers, I didn't find the way to show logs in the Logcat.

After many tries done on my own, here is the (other) way to get logs shown:

[image: Logcat screenshot]

Just selecting `"Show only selected application"` in the combobox did the job. Priorly, it was `"Firebase"` which was selected.

Hopefully, you will see your logs ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I was trying everything. From `log.d` to `log.wtf`. But nothing worked.

Then I restarted my Android Studio. After that, the debugger started working again.

Hope this helps to someone.

Comment: Restarting Studio did not help me. For some reason it does not want to show me verbose messages, but it shows errors. I remember a while ago it did work. Pathetic.

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was that I had actually disabled the logger buffer in my developer settings so go to Settings -> Developer options -> Logger buffer size and set it to anything that isn't 'off'.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem to this one. However in my case the problem was empty first string. It worked in older version of Android Studio, but stopped working in Android Studio ver 5.6 after update.
When I used: 
`Log.d(string1, string2);` in my logging wrapper class,
then whenever string1 was "", the logcat would ignore it. The solution was to add

```
if(string1 == null || string1 == "") {
    string1 = "defaultString";
}
```

before

```
Log.d(string1, string2);
```

I hope this helps anyone with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This started happening with me in Android Studio 3. I was getting old Log.v's printing, but when I added a new one nothing happened. Ditto with debugger breakpoints.

Cleaning the solution and restarting Android Studio worked for me, but there was a simpler solution.

[Disable Instant Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999669/how-to-disable-instant-run-for-android-studio-3-0). It seems that Instant Run doesn't recognise new Log.v's or breakpoints.

Along the way I also added Gradle-aware Make to my Run/Debug configuration for the main activity. I don't know whether that was necessary, but I'm keeping it. (`[Main Menu] Run -> Edit Configurations...`)

[image: Add Gradle-aware Make to Project Run configuration]

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. I switched off and on developer options and usb debugging and all logs worked. i also enabled gpu debug layers in developer options(i dont think that helped).