# Android nmea sentence not logging

Tags: android, gps, nmea

I've got pure and simple Androiod `GPS LocationManager` with `NmeaListener` added to it. In body of `onNmeaReceived()` method I have simple 
`Log.d()` statement. When i tell it to log simple 
`String ("Nmea receied" or something)` - it works ok. 
But when i add received **nmea string to log body** - Log.d simply not showing. But the most weird part - in the debugger **i can see nmea string ("GPRMS and other NMEA 0183 stuff)**. What's wrong with Log.d in this case?

> Problem Log.d looks like that:

```
@Override
public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
    Log.d("Log", "Nmea received " + nmea)
}
```

Comment: Check the `nmea` string, char by char. Maybe it contains some special character that conflicts with the Log.

Comment: In my case, the debugger its only showing as onNmeaReceived only has timestamp, and "nmea" is not defined in method signature. very weird.

Comment: It so weird! You can show the string in a toast, but not in the log console. It also think it is a special char that logging doesn't like.

Comment: Have you checked that post **["Why are Log.d() and Log.v() not printing"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434901/why-are-log-d-and-log-v-not-printing)** ?