# Android logcat error: ZipFileCache: init failed when open zip file - device specific?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Having trouble to get any usefull logs from LogCat.
My app is working fine (both devices), and all logs are fine as well with my Nexus device. 
But with my phone (Huawei P8 Lite, not rooted, Android 5) I am getting this error message :

> 11-12 11:21:07.740: E/ZipFileCache(7584): init failed when open zip
>   file.

I tried to set it back to factory settings, but no luck.

My app is not using ZIP function at all, only accessing internal storage.
I found several post about this on internet but always without solution.
Also tested both Eclipse and Android Studio with same result.

Comment: I have the same messages on the exactly same device. The app works fine though seems to be rather slow when these messages appear. My suspicion is it's a bug of this specific model of phone.

Comment: I have the same problem on the same device.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: with this hack LogCat works : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app

Comment: Just an FYI: If you want to filter these messages you can enable regex in the logcat filter and type: ^((?!zipfilecache).)*$

Answer (score 6):

Same error on my Huawei P8 Lite.
11-30 12:39:56.470 24622-24622/com.xxxx.debug E/ZipFileCache: init failed when open zip file.
I think that is like Codo saids. An internal error on this phone model.
It also makes my device to connect and disconnet several times...
So it isn't a developing problem.

Comment: same problem on Huawei P7. I wrote to Huawei support, they ware polite, but couldn't help