# Android 5.1 ZipFileCache Error - cause and effect?

Tags: java, android

Topic has been opened but not answered for a different device Huawei P8 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669464/android-logcat-error-zipfilecache-init-failed-when-open-zip-file-device-spec)

I`m using Huawei G8 with Andoid 5.1 and get the same error plus another one in Android Studio:

```
1) E/HAL﹕ hw_get_module_by_class: lib loaded: /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8916.so
2) E/ZipFileCache﹕ init failed when open zip file.
```

As i cant comment yet reputation-wise I would like to ask again:

**- what can cause above errors?

- any workaround possible, or is it a vendor-/device specific problem (Huawei)?

- will this effect the final app on release?**

In dev the app is sometimes running slow or seems to sleep due to the errors. They dont appear in the Nexus emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I believe is a device specific problem, I got same error debugging with Huawei G8

```
E/ZipFileCache: init failed when open zip file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error by working with a Huawei Ascend G7.

When I debug with another device (Samsung Galaxy XCover2) that error doesnot appear.

So in my opinion is a device problem.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669464/android-logcat-error-zipfilecache-init-failed-when-open-zip-file-device-spec