# Enable DEBUG logging on Blu R1 HD (Amazon phone)

Tags: android, logging, mobile, runtime, logcat

I bought the `Blu R1 HD`, Amazon's Android phone, for use in dev testing. When I view its logs via logcat, only messages logged at the INFO level or higher are showing up for both my app and other system-related messages.

Yes, developer mode is enabled and ADB Integration is enabled via Android Studio. The same app installed on other devices or the emulator shows the DEBUG and VERBOSE log messages as expected.

I see that some specific phone manufactures have default settings to suppress log messages at runtime, e.g.
[Huawei, logcat not showing the log for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app?rq=1)

Perhaps the Blu phone is doing something similar. Does anyone know of a way to get DEBUG and VERBOSE logs to show up on this particular phone? (It is the low-end version, 8GB storage, and shows Amazon ads on the lock screen.)

Comment: So we still don't know a way?

Comment: How about today?

Answer (score 2):

Daniel, its probably the same exact instructions..

dial

*#*#2846579#*#*

you should see a hidden menu:

Go ProjectMenu / Background Setting / Log setting

change the log setting than reboot phone

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `*#*#2846579#*#*`? Alas it does not work: as soon as I type the final `*` the number display clears but I don't get a menu.

Comment: @DanielDickison did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Caleb_Allen Unfortunately no, I never found a solution. I've gone back to using my old Nexus 4 as my main dev device which continues to work perfectly well.

Comment: @DanielDickison that is unfortunate. I've just bumped up the log level to information, which probably isn't best practice but is necessary in this case.

Comment: @Caleb_Allen Were you able to see the log messages by setting to information?  It doesn't work on my BLU Vivo...

Answer (score 0):

I have a more recent BLU Vivo 5 phone and I noticed that only some of my logcat messages were showing up. After some more experimentation I discovered that the tag names I was using were somehow being filtered.  For example, if I do some logging like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    ....
    ...
    public void test() {
        Log.d("MyClass", "Test log");
        Log.d("MyClass1", "Test log");
        Log.d("TestTag", "Test log");
    }
```

Only the second and third log statements will show up:

```
05-31 18:35:48.812  7294  7294 D TestTag: here
05-31 18:35:48.812  7294  7294 D MyClass1: here
```

On the BLU phone, it seems like there is a tag filter that blocks log messages with tags matching certain criteria.

I'm sure there is a proper explanation but for now, in my app, to get the logcats on the BLU phone, I just simply add an extra space to my tags like so:

```
public class MyLogger {
    public static void d(String tag, String msg) {
        Log.d(tag + " ", msg);
    }
}
```

Btw, just to clarify, I did not have to enter any special # codes in the phone dialer to get log messages to show up.  The logcats just show up by default.