# android app is not executed

Tags: java, android

when the icon of the application is clicked, app is started.

but app is terminated less than 1 second.

please let me know how to fix it.

```
the error message ::

11-05 08:25:54.975 3250-3622/? E/logserver: set_output_postfix: NULL pointer.

11-05 08:25:54.975 3250-3622/? E/logserver: special_handle: NULL pointer.

11-05 08:25:54.978 5099-5213/? E/AprStatisticsFile: null apk name

11-05 08:25:54.983 3699-3715/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build

11-05 08:25:55.015 5099-5212/? E/PackageLogInfoManager: checkPackageLogState, cr: android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver@b6e40d8, packageNames: null

11-05 08:25:55.052 3699-4313/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and spent countless hours debugging through android source code until I found out that **you have to enable logging on Huawei devices manually** and there is no "xy has closed" dialog shown when an app crashes.

It's very likely your app throws a regular exception that just isn't logged by the device to the Android Studio debugger.

See this post for more info on how to enable logging on Huawei phones:
[Huawei, logcat not showing the log for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app)