# Why Log.d and Log.v do not print any output?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

Want to Log something with Log.d, but no output text is appearing in the Android Monitor section. Code is like below?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    insertToDb();
}

private void insertToDb() {
 Log.d("TAG", "Rows count: ");

    }
```

**After restarting nothing changed also:**

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are filtering for error or warning? or maybe you are not selecting correct app on adb debugging part.

Comment: are you using phone or emulator ?, some phone block logs

Comment: I am sure filtering is right, when I use system.out.println, output is there in console, but no result for Log.d in Android monitor tab

Comment: I am using both phone and emulator.

Comment: for *log.d* to show you should set the filtering on verbose or debug

Comment: sometimes android monitor acts strange and wont show anything try restarting android studio and see how it goes

Comment: I know how filtering works, let me restart the PC, until then you guys continue giving me minus sign.

Comment: After all, why there is no output for Log.d and Log.v?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might help
[Huawei, logcat not showing the log for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app/18395092#18395092)

> Dial
>
> ```
> *#*#2846579#*#*
> ```
>
> and you will see a hidden menu. Go to the Project Menu > Background Setting > Log setting and define the log availability (log switch) and level (log level setting).

You might have to enable both AP and CP logs for debug and verbose logs to show.

PS : probably only for Huawei devices.

Comment: you made my day this make me crazy i thought  this is android studio bug

Comment: What about tablets which does not have Dial app? thanks

Comment: Usually there's a corresponding string which can be tried on calculator. I don't know what it is though

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Log.e("TAG", "Rows count: ");
```

For the log to be in red (error) for better visibility.Remember to clear the search bar of the logs pane to display all logs too

Comment: add exception to `Log.e(...);`

Answer (score 0):

It is working. i had tried. but if it is not working in your android studio then check you had selected your device properly or else try to restart the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. 
At first, I was importing Log using this:

```
import com.example.android.common.logger.Log;
```

When I imported Log using this:

```
import android.util.Log;
```

the output appeared.

Answer (score -1):

Its working fine... you need to check log under Debug section as you have used **Log.d**.