# Android: log.d doesn't work while log.i does

Tags: android, logging

i have the following issue programming an android application with android studio. When I use `Log.d(...)` in the code, no logging output is generated while all other logging functions, e.g. `Log.i(...)`, work in exactly the same position.

Example that does not work:

```
 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onStart called.");
 }
```

But this works:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("MainActivity", "onStart called.");
}
```

The Logcat level is set to Debug, the correct device and application are chosen, and as filter I use the Tag "MainActivity". I have already tried to restart logcat, clear the log, nothing successful.

I have also that the logging level with `adb shell setprop log.tag.MainActivity DEBUG` so that `Log.isLoggable("MainActivity", Log.DEBUG)` returns true.

The App is also set to debuggable.

I am very thankful for any hint.

EDIT:
I seems to be an issue with my phone (Honor8). Although it hasn't worked in the emulator as well, executing `adb shell setprop log.tag.MainActivity DEBUG` fixes the problem at least in the emulator.

Comment: If you are sure that solved your problem, you might want to answer your own problem and accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem:

1. For the emulator devices, executing `adb shell setprop log.tag.MainActivity DEBUG` in terminal did the job.
2. For my Honor 8, had additionally to dial `*#*#2846579#*#*` and tick all logging properties, as described here: [Huawei, logcat not showing the log for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app)