# Sony, logcat not showing the log for my app?

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, retrofit, logcat

Logcat is showing all logs: Log.i(), Log.e() but not Log.d().
If I switch to another device such as my Reami 3S then for the same app log is displayed.

Sony is runngin Android 6 and developer options is turn on.

I found my answer where people used secret code for USB control menu, but I can't found for Sony E5 (f3311).

Pls, help me. This logs need me for logging retrofit. Without it I can't show HttpLoggingInterceptor.

Answer (score -4):

You should activate the maximum log level in your device, in the answer below one of the solutions is

> Dial
>
> ```
> *#*#2846579#*#*
> ```
>
> and you will see a hidden menu. Go to the Project Menu > Background Setting > Log setting and define the log availability (log switch) and level (log level setting).

Source: [Huawei, logcat not showing the log for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app/18395092#18395092)