# System Logs on Huawei P30 Pro

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Does anyone have experience with checking system logs within Huawei P30 Pro mobile phone? What system logs does the phone keep? Are there logs to indicate when the phone switches between WiFi and GPRS Mobile Data, for example? If 'yes', could anyone provide an example how these logs look like?

Answer (score 0):

Dial

*#*#2846579#*#*

and you will see a hidden menu. Go to the Project Menu > Background Setting > Log setting and define the log availability (log switch) and level (log level setting).

For details, you could check this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18124334/13329100).